# Can someone explain why this would not create an infinitely rotating disk (perpetual motion)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy-conservation, dissipation, perpetual-motion

This may be a dumb question and the solution may be super obvious but I can't figure it out as hard as I try.
I have drawn a sketch of a device I thought of, now I know that we cant create "Free" energy and I understand that this will not do that, my question is only what stops this disk from infinitely going into motion and accelerating even with the all the resistances that it is under ( friction, air resistance...), the acceleration that the attraction of the magnets produce may be a bit higher than the resistances and so it will accelerate until it reaches max velocity where the disk is simply too fast and the main magnet will not have time to exert enough force to accelerate it.

Explaining the sketch:

1. A perm. magnet with its poles facing left and right.
2. A disk with a ball bearing.
3. 6/8/12/... perm. magnets attached opposite to each other on the disk, with one of their poles facing outwards and one inwards of the disk.

In theory the south pole of the main magnet will attract the north of one of the disk magnets pulling it towards it, the disk should have enough kinetic energy to go past the first pole and the midline (ML) and into the other pole which will repel it, same with the next disk magnet...
with no external source of power this should go into perpetual motion, so can you please explain what I am not seeing here.

My theories so far are as follows:

1. The main magnetic field will never be powerful enough to sling the disk magnet past the midline (ML) where it can be repelled, so the device will reach stability short after the first attraction.
2. The energy created by the magnets is less than the one taken by resistances and the device will slowly lose its initial kinetic energy and come to a stop. But what about in space and with negligible friction??
3. Energy is created by the device but it is only a conversion of "stored" energy in the form of the permanent magnets, and every time we extract energy from it (by letting it run until max V and then using its kinetic energy), we are essentially using the energy we put initially to create this permanent magnet.
4. (Not sure about this one) The south poll even if its inside the disk and much farther away from the north will still resist the motion enough that it will stop the disk

Thankyou all in advance..

Sorry but I drew this in paint.

[image: Sry but i made this on paint.]

Comment: In your image, the N side of the bar will push counter-clockwise just as hard as the S side pushes clockwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that the accepted laws of physics don't allow this to happen. Energy cannot be created or destroyed so your system could not get kinetic energy from nothing. Finding 'exactly' what is wrong with a specific perpetual motion machine can be a laborious process, but in your case it is fairly simple.

I made a very simple magnetic model that approximates your device (I put the magnets in a straighe line rather than in a circle as shown below, but teh results would be the same in either case.
[image]

If you now calculate the force on the moving magnet as a function of position you get a plot like the following:
[image]

So when the moving magnet passes one of the row of static magnets there is a strong horizontal force in one direction, and when it is between magnets there is a weaker force in the opposite direction.

In simple terms, the strong force over a short distance accelerates the magnet by exactly as much as the weaker force (in the opposite direction that acts over a longer distance) decelerates it. To confirm this, if you integrate the area under the +ve force section (red hatched area), you will find that this is exactly equal to the integrated area under the -ve force section (green hatched area). So the net work done on the moving magnet as it accelerates and decelerates is zero - i.e. its kinetic energy after completing one pass will be unchanged so in your design it will only move until friction in the bearings brings it to a halt.

In answ

Comment: I think  it is not just friction,permanent magnets  will slowly become demagnetized. see adverse fields here https://www.adamsmagnetic.com/blogs/factors-which-cause-permanent-magnets-lose-strength-or-demagnetize/

Comment: A typical rare earth magnet, used in the system described by the OP, will only be demagnetized by the tinyest fraction - even if the disk was manually rotated past the stationary magnet for years. And regardless of that, slow demagnetization would neither add or subrtract from the kinetic energy of the system.

Comment: The demagnetization of the magnet is the only reason I found this system hard to understand, external energy is technically given to the system when the magnet is magnetized, but this clears things up.  I know that perpetual motion is impossible thus I made this post so I can understand what's wrong with this one, this helped a lot and it makes sense now, thankyou.